# Preserving my first Minecraft game on Ubuntu 22.04.1 from earlier Ubuntu server

Tags: server, ssh, java, games, minecraft

My first Minecraft game was 1.8.8 on my local Windows machine.  I built a stand-alone Ubuntu Server 16.04 (actually probably started as 14.04 but upgraded along the way) and did a build of Spigot 1.8.8 and put the world there. The game is running fine on that original server, but I feel its time for an upgrade, so I've built another stand-alone with Ubuntu Server 22.04.1, adding nothing in the installation except for SSH, and Samba after.

I followed [DigitalOcean's](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-minecraft-server-on-ubuntu-22-04) instructions to install the Minecraft on the new server, giving me a working 1.18.2 game.

Next, I used scp to copy my 1.8.8 game folder to the new server.  In the ssh terminal the game loads properly, either with the spigot .jar or with a mojang, and I get the "Done" message, but when I try to join from my Windows Minecraft client, I get 'java.io.ioexception...' and the text in the ssh terminal turns into a blur.  The standard CTL+C, X, Q don't stop the blur of text, and the only thing I've found I can do is close out ssh and reopen a new session.

I've tried:

1. A new build of the latest from [SpigotMC](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/buildtools/), first without installing java on the new server since I used DigitalOcean's instructions to do that already, then going back and installing SpigotMC's `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless` except for `git` they recommended because I already had that.
2. Disabling all the plugins I'd added at some point
3. The aforementioned trying both spigot_1.8.8.jar vs. mojang's
4. Adjusting the arguments for both the server start.sh and the client's to both more and less memory.
5. Changing ports and and online-mode in `server.properties`
6. Adding firewall rules
7. Reboots of both client and server.

I haven't tried:

1. Changing DNS as suggested in posts dating back to 2016-7, because without even restarting the server after the crash, I can go back in a new ssh session and successfully get Minecraft 1.8.8 to completely load.  Also, without restarting I can get the DigitalOcean installed Minecraft working fully, with no error when joining.
2. Resetting the router for the same reasons as #1

Has anybody run into this problem and come up with a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Does Minecraft have its own support site?

Comment: @David, they do, but this issue seems closer to an Ubuntu-java interaction issue, probably from something I've done wrong.  The game itself shows itself to be loaded on the server successfully but on connection attempts I get the error.  Also, I'd started using 3rd party built .jar files.